# weird JavaScript exception in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, apache, google-chrome, wampserver

Ok I have an unexpected identifier exception being raised in the Chrome Console.

This is the code that is in my JavaScript file:

```
function url_checker(link){

   // var expression = /^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$//gi;
    // var regex = new RegExp(expression);

    // if (link.match(regex))
    // {

    //     return true;

    // }

    // return false;

}
```

As you can see everything is commented out.

In chrome the console throws this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

And obviously points to the document and line where the error was picked up. So I click on the line and chrome brings up my JavaScript file with the following lines of code:

```
function url_checker(link){

   // var expression = /^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.(HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 26 Mar 2015 22:30:30 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12
Last-Modified: Thu, 26 Mar 2015 22:30:28 GMT
ETag: "8139-5123890136730"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 33081
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/javascript
```

Does anyone know what this means and why on earth it is happening?

Comment: The code itself does not produce an error, so the problem might be with the code that comes *before* this one.

Comment: Well, I can tell you that stuff after the start of the code is the start of an HTTP response for a JavaScript file.  The server has PHP on it which is probably to blame somehow.

Comment: This can't be replicated since the code does nothing, it must be somewhere else where the error occurs.

Comment: The document has over 1500 lines of code which has both normal functional JavaScript and AJAX calls. Do you think that the AJAX calls is responsible?

Comment: Is this error reproducible? Your server (that served the script file) seems to have had a hiccup, or is buggy.

Comment: @Bergi I use WAMPSERVER 2.5... The site was working absolutely fine last week, I think this might be the problem.

Comment: Just a guess but! Try removing the first line completely, i.e. the line with the regex string in it. Possibly having all those escape chars in it is undoing the comment somehow or at least confusing something somewhere in the pipeline.